# HTML5/CSS3 text editor for OS X?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a text editor that supports HTML5 and CSS3, allowing you to add/edit new properties, like rounded corners and so.

It doesn't have to be a visual editor but **it has to have support for CSS3** and other new stuff like rounded corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Espresso on a daily basis. You'll need to the [HTML5 sugar](https://github.com/minimalweb/HTML5.sugar) and the [CSS3 sugar](https://github.com/minimalweb/CSS3.sugar) to get the code completion.

Espresso also have a preview functionality that helps a lot in developing a page with minute differences.

Answer (score 4):

There are two all-in-one solutions specialised for web development: [Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/) from Panic and [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) from MacRabbit. Both have their pros and cons, just try them out and see which fits better for your needs. [Hype](https://tumult.com/hype/) is going through the news recently, but is more tool to create interactive and flashy HTML5 sites (as far as I understood it).

Comment: For example I was not able to find the support for rounded corners in Coda.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's still no new version of CSSEdit with CSS3 support, but if rounded corners are the only problem, you can use one of dozens web generators, for example: [cssround.com](http://cssround.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you have Textmate, there's are CSS3 bundles available.

- http://code.google.com/p/webkit-css3-bundle/

  > A bundle of advanced CSS3 features supported by Apple's open source Webkit and Safari browsers. These features are primarily limited to those prefixed with -webkit.
- http://zeroedandnoughted.com/css3-textmate-bundle/

  > I’ve combined the previous CSS3 TextMate Snippets into a bundle, which was a lot easier to do than I thought it would be. I’ll detail how to make your own in a future post.

Answer (score 2):

Please use "Visual Studio Code". This is simple to use and you can switch from mac to windows and vice-versa without problem. There is a lot of extensions to write code without error and faster. Many tutorials and projects are coded on Visual Studio Code. Many firm use it.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5 there's a new App, called [Hype](http://tumultco.com/hype/) which seems to be very interesting (see the videos).

For CSS Specific stuff, I had great success with [CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/) from MacRabbit, but I'm not a graphic designer so my success is very limited in that area :)